# MediaWiki: Branch an Article

Tags: mediawiki

Let me first state that I've tried searching [MediaWiki's Website](http://www.mediawiki.org) , Google, superuser, and stack overflow stackoverflow. In addition I've tried searching for a MediaWiki centric site, and the closest I came up with was [this Area51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikis-and-wikipedia). Because this isn't programming related I've decided to post it here in superuser, should this be the wrong place please feel free to move it.

MediaWiki supports a version control concept with its articles which is great. However I'd like to take this one step further and have the ability to 'Branch' an article or a set of articles at a given time. A simple use case example of this would be that I have a MediaWiki setup to document our software, every time we branch a new version of our software it'd be nice to maintain two separate wikipages for each version of our software should it change drastically between versions.

As stated before a Google search and digging around in MediaWiki itself did not show any apparent ability to do this. A poor mans way of doing this would be to copy the contents of the article into a new page, however this would be time consuming and we'd lose all the existing revision history. This may end up needing to be a feature request for the kids down at MediaWiki.

Thank you.

*Edit*
I probably should have mentioned that we're using MediaWiki 1.15.2, but we're not opposed to upgrading to the latest and greatest if the feature exists in a higher version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki doesn't have this feature built-in, and templates (mentioned above) will unfortunately not help you with this particular task.

You'll need to install a MediaWiki extension to accomplish it. The main one i know of is [Duplicator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Duplicator), which should work with your version of MW.

If you're unfamiliar with MW extensions, usually all you need to do is copy the files into the wiki `extensions` directory and then add a `require_once()` line (see link) to the end of your `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: Thank you this is close to what I'm looking for, however the lack of a 'mass copy' ability has me still looking. I'll leave the question open a bit longer to see if anyone else has any suggestions. If nothing else happens I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use (with some adaptation) [MediaWiki templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates)

Comment: I do not believe Templates will do what I want, we use them extensively and I believe you maybe referring to the transclusion feature, which will give you a duplicate of the page content as it exists. I want a separate copy.

Comment: @aolszowka, there is really no difference. Every page can be transcluded; it becomes a "template" when it actually is. :) A page could contain the shared content and then each "branch" would contain the parts which differ.